# Online Device Not visible on Eclipse Android Device Chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, android-debug

[image: Online Device Not visible on Android Device Chooser]

I have been trying to run my android project on different devices but my Android Device Chooser doesn't seem to be detecting them. USB Debugging is enabled on my device. The Minimum API version is 10 and Target API version is 19.

I have tried all options listed in similar questions but none of them seems to work for me. Has anyone else faced this issue before?

Comment: did you tried to restart adb ?

Comment: @HugoGresse Yes I tried that. But as you can notice it is already listed in adb.

Comment: did you tried with changing the sdk target version in android manifest file ?

Comment: can you reconnect usb cable and check if you get any kind of pop..

Comment: Also check if adb drivr of your device is installed into your pc

Comment: @chain I tried changing target versions. and that link doesn't not say anything that I have not already tried.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738236/run-app-with-real-device-but-it-doesnt-work/27738315#27738315 this. Both are same I think.

Comment: @AmanTonk the adb driver is installed

Comment: @virendrao When i reconnect my device the Android File transfer app pops up nothing else.

Comment: disable usb debugging , disconnect and follow steps again. Did you accept rsa security key persmission which comes when you connect for first time

Comment: @virendrao's comment usually works and also try `adb devices` in your terminal

Comment: @Droidekas `adb devices` list my device

Comment: @glo restart devices do your steps again and restart and check

Comment: @virendrao Tried that and with different devices too.

Comment: connect your device,then switch off and switch on developer options

Comment: @Droidekas I have tried that too

Answer (score 0):

Tried to Change targeted API from Google API to 19,20 or 21.